# Absolutely Free PDF Tools (Compress, Merge, Split, etc) software for Windows. (Not Web Based)

Tags: windows, pdf

I need a **completely free** PDF tools app which could Merge, Split, Compress, Reduce, Crop, etc and all other features and that too without any payment of any money.

Also it should **not be cloud based or web based**... it should completely work in offline and as a windows software.

If it is not there, then **atleast** suggest an **android** based native app fot the same functionalities

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please suggest another android native (offline, non-cloud based) pdf app for the same functionalities....?

Comment: I also want to know, Why there are no good open source softwares for such PDf functionalities ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [PDF Arranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger). It is free and open source. It can merge, split, rotate, crop, and rearrange PDF files. However, it has no ability to compress PDF files. It is available for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: It doesn't have such facilities as you have mentioned. It only has page rearranging option.

Comment: @VengadeshwaranS To merge two PDF files, you add two PDF files, not just one. To split a PDF file, you delete pages. To rotate and crop pages, select the pages you want to rotate/crop and use the buttons in the toolbar to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share an application that has pdf file size reduction feature ?

Comment: @VengadeshwaranS, please tick the answer, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

QPDF is a good option:

https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf

> QPDF is a command-line tool and C++ library that performs content-preserving
> transformations on PDF files. It supports linearization, encryption, and
> numerous other features. It can also be used for splitting and merging files,
> creating PDF files (but you have to supply all the content yourself), and
> inspecting files for study or analysis.